# php - how to convert actionscript rich text to plain text?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash-builder, richtext

I have a flex (flash builder 4) application with a rich text editor control.   I am storing this rich text output in a database via zend amf <--> php.

Now I want to display the first part of that text in a data grid.  To do so it seems it might be easiest to get the plain text version.

I am hoping I can somehow convert it to plain text in PHP before I pass it back to flex?

Comment: I bet some ReGex would strip out all the "Rich Text" tags easy enough.  But, as point of clarification, you can get the value in many Flex components, usually using htmlText for rich text, and text for plain text.  Why not store the plain text to start?

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Strip tags makes sense that it might work in php, but another option is to use the [text](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_02.html) property of the rich text field which retrieves the plain text version of the text.    For example, in flex, load up the rich text from the db in to an in-memory rich text component, then get the plain text from that to display in the grid.